# Using secondary y-axis in ggplot2 with different scale factor when using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis, facet-wrap

Suppose I have the following data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

data = structure(list(origin = c("ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "CHL", 
"CHL", "CHL", "CHL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "COL", "MEX", "MEX", 
"MEX", "MEX"), date = c(2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015), reer = c(99.200680735245, 
88.1100217095859, 91.138945064955, 38.2318792759958, 97.1355065168361, 
96.1872670893033, 93.6345905776444, 92.1029850680499, 101.123844098755, 
94.173001658586, 77.1226216761908, 59.6337376438912, 98.0983258996167, 
97.6713495865999, 92.2842729861424, 86.2605669691898), x_r = c(0.0874733578362671, 
0.0815610804254794, 0.0783917054809495, 0.0579932868099816, 0.178204232427659, 
0.16321408066481, 0.170084977520404, 0.151329817378872, 0.0498810245214703, 
0.0429419825495197, 0.0383271589817956, 0.0413797639710004, 0.246549060641858, 
0.242694346464116, 0.236773340112642, 0.269553103263527)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), groups = structure(list(
    origin = c("ARG", "CHL", "COL", "MEX"), .rows = list(1:4, 
        5:8, 9:12, 13:16)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I'm trying to make a plot using `facet_wrap` along with a secondary y-axis using `sec.axis` option of `scale_y_continuous`. So far what I got is the following:

```
scale = 500

ggplot(data, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x_r), size = 2, color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = reer/scale), size = 2, color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(.~origin, ncol = 4, scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "X/GDP",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scale, name = "REER")
  ) +   
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", size = 13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue", size = 13)
  ) +
  ggtitle("Export Ratio and Real Effective Exchange Rate")
```

[image]

However, the `scale` factor I'm using is constant (scale = 500) for all the countries, I'd like to have a different scale factor for each country. Something like `scaleFactor1 = max(x_r)/max(reerr)`. I know what `sec.axis` option of `scale_y_continuous`makes is a linear combination of the principal y-axis, but I want it to be different for each country. I've tried the following, but it does not work:

```
data = data %>% 
  group_by(origin) %>% 
  mutate(scaleFactor = max(x_r)/max(reerr)) %>% 
  mutate(reer_2 = reerr/scaleFactor)

ggplot(data, aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = x_r), size = 2, color = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = reer), size = 2, color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(.~origin, ncol = 4, scales = "free_y") + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "X/GDP",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleFactor, name = "REER")
  ) +   
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", size = 13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue", size = 13)
  ) +
  ggtitle("Export Ratio and Real Effective Exchange Rate")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to split the data on country and create individual plots, saving them to a list. Then use the **cowplot** package to plot them in a grid layout, similar to `facet_wrap` from **ggplot**.

This is your code to create the plots, minus the facet_wrap, and creating scaleFactor, and a Country object for the titles.

```
myPlot <- function(data){

  scaleFactor <- max(data$reer) / max(data$x_r)
  Country <- data$origin

  p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = date)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = x_r), size = 2, color = "red") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = reer/scaleFactor), size = 2, color = "blue") +
    #facet_wrap(.~origin, ncol = 4, scales = "free_y") + 
    scale_y_continuous(
      name = "X/GDP",
      sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*scaleFactor, name = "REER")
    ) +   
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", size = 13),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue", size = 13)
    ) +
    ggtitle(Country)
  p
}
```

Now `split` the data on origin and use `lapply` to call the `myPlot` function.

```
data2 <- split(data, data$origin)
p_lst <- lapply(data2, myPlot)
```

Make a title plot and use `plot_grid` to arrange them in a grid.

```
p0 <- ggplot() + labs(title="Export Ratio and Real Effective Exchange Rate")

library(cowplot)

p1 <- plot_grid(plotlist=p_lst, ncol=2)
pp <- plot_grid(p0, p1, ncol=1, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
```

---

[image]