# Determining the Scale factor for the secondary Y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

The `dput(Q_Sheet)` is below. How can properly introduce a second y-axis that is different in scale from the primary axis?

```
structure(list(Amino_acids = c(4, 12, 20, 28, 32), Protein_length_Ang = c(7, 
24, 40, 56, 64), length_no_ratio = c(1.75, 2, 2, 2, 2), Corrected_aa = c(1.24459201924769e-12, 
3.71007650662474e-09, 1.10594599229843e-05, 0.0319159404863842, 
0.642857142857143), aa_frequency = c(3.99735380592756, 6.96840672963299, 
4.58228895300999, 3.12310921028256, 4.67560843680985), T_degC = c(50.3857804818545, 
52.8464583426248, 60.0760389538482, 58.1895053328481, 67.628202708438
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, `4` = 4L, `6` = 6L), class = "omit"))
`
```

```
ggplot(data = Q_Sheet, aes(x = T_degC))+
       geom_line(aes(y = Amino_acids), color="red")+
       geom_line(aes(y = Corrected_aa), color = "blue") + 
scale_y_continuous(name = "Amino_acids", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Corrected_aa"))
```

The output is as follows:

```
     <ScaleContinuousPosition>
 Range:  
 Limits:    0 --    1
```

Comment: There is a typo.  it should be `scale_y_continuous`

Comment: There is an update. Please see the output.

Comment: Now, there is a missing `+`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using secondary y-axis in ggplot2 with different scale factor when using facet\_wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565304/using-secondary-y-axis-in-ggplot2-with-different-scale-factor-when-using-facet-w)

Comment: actually I wanted to point to this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below formula to keep the secondary Y-axis at the same level as `Corrected_aa`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=Q_Sheet, aes(x=T_degC))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Amino_acids),color="red")+
  geom_line(aes(y=Corrected_aa),color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Amino_acids",
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~{
                       a <- min(Q_Sheet$Corrected_aa)
                       b <- max(Q_Sheet$Corrected_aa)
                       ((((b-a) * (. - min(.)))/diff(range(.))) + a)
                      },name="Corrected_aa"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for assistance here!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues - 1) `scale_y_continuous` typo and 2) there is a missing `+` connecting the last expression

```
ggplot(data=Q_Sheet, aes(x=T_degC))+
             geom_line(aes(y=Amino_acids),color="red")+
             geom_line(aes(y=Corrected_aa),color="blue") +
             scale_y_continuous(name="Amino_acids",
        sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*10,name="Corrected_aa"))
```

-ouptut

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the correction and help! While it is not advised to have two y-axis,  is there a better way to find the correct factor for my secondary y-x scale?

Answer (score 0):

We could define a coefficient and then color the lines to indicate wich lines belongs to which y-scale:

```
library(ggplot2)

value used to transform the data
coeff <- 0.01

# colors
Amino_acidsColor = "red"
Corrected_aaColor = "blue"

ggplot(data=Q_Sheet, aes(x=T_degC))+
  geom_line(aes(y=Amino_acids), size = 2, color=Amino_acidsColor)+
  geom_line(aes(y=Corrected_aa/coeff), size = 2, color=Corrected_aaColor) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Amino_acids",
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~.*coeff,name="Corrected_aa")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = Amino_acidsColor, size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = Corrected_aaColor, size=13)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: TarJae, how did you know the coef would be 0.010? Is there a formula you used?

Comment: Coeff is arbitrary and up to you which factor you take to transform your data. While you could use the formula used by Ronak or akrun. In my opinion in both cases the corrected_aa y axis does not show the values in detail, which in essence is the job of the second y axis.