# In R, how to set up two secondary y-axis with different scales using facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet-wrap

I have below data

```
dataA=structure(list(x = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40,  
50, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 0, 10, 20,  30, 40, 50, 
0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50), part = c("leaf", "leaf",  "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", 
"leaf", "head", "head", "head", "head",  "head", "head", "grain", "grain", 
"grain", "grain", "grain",  "grain", "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", "leaf", 
"leaf", "head",  "head", "head", "head", "head", "head", "grain", "grain", 
"grain",  "grain", "grain", "grain"), nitrogen = c("high", "high", "high",  
"high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high",  "high", 
"high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high", "low",  "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low",  "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
"low", "low", "low"), y = c(0,  5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 0, 1, 15, 30, 45, 60, 0, 
0, 2, 5, 8, 80, 0,  4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 0, 0.8, 12, 24, 36, 48, 0, 0, 1.6, 
4, 6.4,  64)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
row.names = c(NA,  -36L))
```

and I made a area graph using geom_area.

```
ggplot(data=dataA, aes(x=x, y=y))+
  geom_area(aes(group=part, fill=part), position="stack", 
            linetype=1, size=0.5 ,colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue","darkred","khaki4"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,50,10),limits=c(0,50))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,165,30),limits=c(0,165),
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./165, name="Percent total (%)"))+
  facet_wrap(~ nitrogen, scales="free") +
  theme_classic(base_size=18, base_family="serif")+
  theme(axis.line=element_line(linewidth=0.5, colour="black"))+
windows(width=10, height=5)
```

I divided the panels using `facet_wrap()`, and when I added a second y-axis, the range was different. At high nitrogen levels, the final accumulated value (when x is 50) was 165, and I divided it by 165 to set up 100% on the second y-axis. However, at low nitrogen levels, the accumulated value was 132. As a result, the graph (when x is 50) did not reach 100%.

In this case, how can I achieve that? I want the graph (when x is 50) to reach 100% in both panels.

Could you let me know how to do that?

Always many thanks,

[image]

Comment: What package is the last `windows` line from? (I suggest omitting it if it just controls an aesthetic / output option that is unrelated your core question.)

Comment: I don't know of a way to vary the secondary axis scaling by facet. I think this related question is a good approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61565304/using-secondary-y-axis-in-ggplot2-with-different-scale-factor-when-using-facet-w

Comment: @JonSpring that is a base R function, only available in windows. Some base R functions are OS specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be the `ggh4x` package which via `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` allows to individually set the scale per panel including the secondary axis:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = dataA, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_area(aes(group = part, fill = part),
    position = "stack",
    linetype = 1, linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkblue", "darkred", "khaki4")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 50, 10), limits = c(0, 50)) +
  facet_wrap(~nitrogen, scales = "free") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    y = list(
      nitrogen == "high" ~ scale_y_continuous(
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 165, name = "Percent total (%)")
      ),
      nitrogen == "low" ~ scale_y_continuous(
        sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 132, name = "Percent total (%)")
      )
    )  
  ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18, base_family = "serif") +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(linewidth = 0.5, colour = "black"))
```

[image]